# The picture does not show in this Frame?

Tags: java

I have a problem with this following piece of code: the photo does not show in my `JFrame`...
Please help me.

### My Java code:

```
public class ImageRead extends JFrame {
    JPanel pan;
    Image img1;

    public ImageRead() throws IOException {
        this.pan = new JPanel();
        final Dimension d = new Dimension(500, 500);
        this.img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\KHALED\\workspace\\"
                        + "Universite Base De Donner\\src\\2.jpg"));
        this.pan.setPreferredSize(d);
        this.pan.add(new JButton("entre"));
        this.pan.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.getContentPane().add(this.pan);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);

    }

    public void paintComponents(final Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.drawImage(this.img1, 0, 0, this.pan);
        g2.finalize();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ImageRead();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with this, but probably the primary one is that you don't want to override paintComponent of the JFrame, you want to do that on the ContentPane. So create a JPanel derived class, and do that code in there, then call myframe.setContentPane(mypanel);

another issue is you don't want to call finalize() on g2

Chances are you want to use a classpath resource to load that image, rather than using File io.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a proper layout and a real ImageIcon. Also, did you mean `destroy();` instead of `g2.finalize();`?